# Why isn't MariaDB 10.2 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic)?

Tags: 18.04, release-management, mariadb

I'm just trying to understand the release process here,

- [Ubuntu 18.04 had a Debian feature freeze on 2018-03-01](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule).
- [MariaDB 10.2 has a general release on 2017-03-23](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/changes-improvements-in-mariadb-102/)

That means the General Release for MariaDB 10.2 was **11 months** before the feature freeze for 18.04. Why didn't 10.2 make it into 18.04?

*I know I can get the package, I want to know specifically about the Canonical's maintenance policy* Especially being MariaDB 10.1 is supported  upstream until October 2020, while Ubuntu 18.04 is supported until April 2023 (meaning I'm trusting Canonical to support MariaDB 2.5 years longer than MariaDB itself intends to support it).

Comment: It could be that there is no logical answer at all and just hasn't made it across the desk of that developer yet. I'm sure it will be added in a update at some point.

Comment: @EODCraftStaff well, I've LEVELED up to [unix.se] so I've got a lot of unicorn points I can spend to satisfy my morbid curiosity. COME WIN MY BOUNTY.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MariaDB is in the universe pocket of the Ubuntu archive, so the package maintenance relies on volunteers rather than being a Canonical commitment. Please note that Canonical's commitment to provide security updates is about packages in main, not all the universe packages.

Ubuntu syncs and/or merges from Debian sid, and [10.1 is what's still available there](https://packages.debian.org/sid/mariadb-server). Somebody has [packaged 10.3 in Debian experimental](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/mariadb-server), and you may want to make an attempt to install it from there.

Not much more to say, I think. Nobody to blame really.

Comment: Wasn't looking to blame anyone , I guess if it's not in Debian that's both amazing and something I didn't know. I thought Debian's build farms would keep up with all this stuff.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Keeping up with the latest of everything doesn't happen automatically, but manual work is needed. Volunteers handle the bulk of the packages, and since there are always fewer volunteers than you would want, some packages will lag occationally.

Comment: Debian sometimes acts at a snails pace. The 10.3 package was uploaded to experimental 15 months ago but has yet to go to sid which is what Ubuntu syncs from..

Comment: I think it's worth noting that MySQL is in main in Ubuntu, is supported by Canonical, and was reasonably current at the time of release of 18.04. In general (there are a few exceptions) Canonical tends to focus on "one of each thing" to support in main. If you care about receiving support from Canonical, then It's worth keeping this in mind when making a choice of what technology or technology variant to use.